# Ubuntu12.04 GTK+ theme problem

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk3

I try to install a gtk3 theme called 'A New Start' following the instructions on some websites, but when I change the gtk+ theme by using tweak tool, my font turns white and it's really horrible...

[image: Screenshot]

Has anyone got a solution ? or have you ever got the same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your using Advanced Settings to change your theme.
What you have done is selcted your GTK Theme (that is the correct thing to do.).

You also need to change the **Windows theme** from "Ambiance" to "A New Start" also.

It is the second dropbox down in your screenshot.

Comment: I really have done everything I should do. But it really doesn't work...And according to the 'readme' guide, the gtk3 engines are installed, too.

Comment: I just completed a test of the New Hope Theme.  I downloaded both the GTk2 version and the GTK3 version.  GTK3 worked perfectly and GTk2 caused similar issues to you.  Are you sure you downloaded the GTk3 version and not v2?

Comment: Could u tell me what are the differences between installing gtk2 and gtk3 themes ? My package contains folders(gnome-shell, gtk-2.0, gtk-3.0, metacity-1, unity, index.theme). How to tell my system to use gtk3 theme ?

Comment: that's the correct one to use. Iwas just making sure. There are still Gtk2 only versions out there. I used one of these to do the test. You seem to have it installed correctly, I will look into it more